# PTR record won`t update

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, ptr-record

Currently, my server is running Ubuntu Server. I had the domain "rosresurs.msk.ru". A bit later I've bought a new domain called "rosresurs.net". But when I ran dig command, I saw, that old domain is linked to my server's IP. I've looked to both DNS zones. In .msk.ru there is no server's IP. Domain .net has PTR record. Also, I asked for help my domain hosting. Thay said, that it is out fault. I've searched the whole system for rosresurs.msk.ru and its IP address. I've deleted all that entries. But after 2 days nothing changed.

[image: Screenshot of rosresurs.net domain dns zone]

[image: Screenshot of dig command for server's IP address]

Answer (score 3):

That's because the `PTR` record isn't configured in either of these zones, but the *reverse* `in-addr.arpa.` zone of the IP block.

Contact your ISP (or who ever owns the IP address) to change it. For your IP that'd be:

```
inetnum:        151.248.116.0 - 151.248.119.255
netname:        REGRU-NETWORK
descr:          Reg.Ru Hosting
country:        RU
```