# Bad DNS PTR resource record

Tags: domain-name-system, email

i am running my own Mailserver, which works fine, but not for some targets. Basically I can send mails to everybody, except to `*@gmx.net` and `*@web.de`, If I do that, it takes about an week and then I get a `Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender` mail. Within that I find that error:

```
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554-gmx.net (mxgmx114) Nemesis ESMTP Service not
available 554-No SMTP service 554-Bad DNS PTR resource record.
```

I have been googling for that and found some explanation, but I still do not know what to put where in the `DNS` record.

Right now I have that in the `TXT` part of the `DNS`

```
v=spf1 a mx ptr -all
```

But it is not working.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this answer.](https://serverfault.com/a/861124/327632)

> That's because the PTR record isn't configured in either of these
>   zones, but the reverse in-addr.arpa. zone of the IP block.
>
> Contact your ISP (or who ever owns the IP address) to change it.

Comment: I own the Domain. I can add A,MX and TXT records. Is there a way to do that using those settings only?

Comment: @philipp no, it's not possible, as you can see error `554-Bad DNS PTR resource record` is PTR related, so you should ask your provider to set PTR entry.